# Automating selection of radio buttons in web form filling through vba

Tags: html, excel, radio-button, vba

I am trying to automate this website using VBA excel. I am struck at a point where I have to select between `2 radio buttons`. As I am new in VBA so really confuse about the coding part for these radio buttons.
here is **HTML** script for the radio button.

```
<li class="required or ok" id="petGenderLI">
            <div class="formElTop" id="petGenderMainDiv">
                <div class="leftCol" id="petGenderLeftDiv">

<label id="yourPetGenderField-label"><span class="petNameToReplace">Your pet</span>'s <span style="white-space: nowrap;">Gender</span></label>

</div>
                <div class="rightCol radios" id="petGenderRightDiv">
                    <div class="buttonLeft">
                        <input name="pets[0].gender" class="radio" id="yourDetailsPolicyHolderPetGender-f0" type="radio" value="NWA_PET_M" data-di-field-id="pets0Gender"><label for="yourDetailsPolicyHolderPetGender-f0">Male</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttonRight">
                        <input name="pets[0].gender" class="radio" id="yourDetailsPolicyHolderPetGender-m0" type="radio" value="NWA_PET_F" data-di-field-id="pets0Gender"><label for="yourDetailsPolicyHolderPetGender-m0">Female</label>
                    </div>

                </div><span class="errorIcon">&nbsp;</span><div class="errorMessage"><div class="errorTop"><div class="errorContent"></div></div></div>
                <div class="clearFloat" id="petGenderTailDiv">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the HTML you have supplied you can grab the option buttons by their className which is `option`. You don't show enough HTML to be sure this will limit to the two in sample given. Assuming they do, this returns the following (assume the `"."`  in the image below is `className` and that the entire query string of `.option` is the same as `.document.getElementsByClassName("radio")`. I have replicated the VBA with a CSS query on the HTML.

**CSS query: This shows you what elements are captured by the code below**

[image: CSS query]

---

**VBA code outline:**

We target the option buttons by their class name with the `.getElementsByClassName` method of the HTML document returned by the instance of IE navigating to the URL and post load. This is a 0 base collection that is returned (as you can see in image above), so you access items by index starting at 0 for first option.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "yourURL"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim radioButtons As Object
        Set radioButtons = .document.getElementsByClassName("radio")
        radioButtons(0).Click                    '<== first option
        radioButtons(1).Click                    '<== first option

        'Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With
End Sub
```